# Panel overlay in Sencha touch 2

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, panel, sencha-touch-2

I have been working on an application using sencha touch 2 .
I have a toolbar on top which contains a button .
When i click this button i will have a panel overlay .
In this panel,i want to have two items :

```
    var shareButton = {
                    xtype : 'button',
                    ui: 'action',
                    width:'36px',
                    height:'36px',  
                    handler : function(){ 
                    var panel=Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
            right: 0,
            top: 20,
            modal: true,
            hideOnMaskTap: true,
            hidden: true,   
            width: 260,
            height:'70%' ,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

items: [
{html:'<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="https://www.google.com" data-lang="en">Tweet</a></body>',},
{html:'<div ><class="fb-like" data-href="http://test.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="4" data-show-faces="false"></div>'}]});
    Ext.Viewport.add(panel);
    panel.show();}};
```

But this is not working.
In fact,i want the first one to direct me to twitter to share the URL (www.google.com).
And the second one to facebook to share "test.com".

Unfortunately ,nothing is displayed in the panel .
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the overlay is called after the page is loaded, the facebook and twitter buttons should rendered again

This is the code that should be added after the overlay is shown

```
FB.XFBML.parse();//facebook
$.ajax({ url: 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true}); //twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. THe only problem is that the Facebook like button has not got a size, so you cannot see it.

Ensure your floating panel is not scrollable. If it is scrollable, give it a fixed width and height.

**Update**

Here is an example on Sencha Fiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#jgXtj

Ensure you are adding the panel into `Ext.Viewport`.

Comment: I tried the two cases:1) scrollable and fixed width and height And 2)Scrollable false .Not fixed

Comment: i followed your example .The panel is actually working but the FB like button doesn't appear and the twitter icon doesn't show :S

Comment: Only the word tweet appears which allows me to access twitter.com

Comment: Yup, that is because the Facebook like button doesn't have a fixed height. So you'll need either need to style it in CSS or by using the `width` and `height` properties in that container.